# Python - Parse string, known structure

Tags: python, regex, string

I have to parse a list of simple strings with a known structure but I'm finding it unnecessarily clunky. 
I feel I'm missing a trick, perhaps some simple regex that would make this trivial?

The string refers to some number of years/months in the future, I want to make this into decimal years.

Generic format: "aYbM"

Where a is the number of years, b is the number of months these can be ints and both are optional (along with their identifier)

Test cases:

```
5Y3M == 5.25
5Y == 5.0
6M == 0.5
10Y11M = 10.91666..
3Y14M = raise ValueError("string '%s' cannot be parsed" %input_string)
```

My attempts so far have involved string splitting and been pretty cumbersome though they do produce the correct results:

```
def parse_aYbM(maturity_code):
    maturity = 0
    if "Y" in maturity_code:
        maturity += float(maturity_code.split("Y")[0])
        if "M" in maturity_code:
            maturity += float(maturity_code.split("Y")[1].split("M")[0]) / 12
        return maturity
    elif "M" in maturity_code:
        return float(maturity_code[:-1]) / 12
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the regex pattern

```
(?:(\d+)Y)?(?:(\d+)M)?
```

which means

```
(?:        start a non-grouping pattern
  (\d+)    match 1-or-more digits, grouped
  Y        followed by a literal Y
)?         end the non-grouping pattern; matched 0-or-1 times
(?:        start another non-grouping pattern
  (\d+)    match 1-or-more digits, grouped
  M        followed by a literal M
)?         end the non-grouping pattern; matched 0-or-1 times
```

When used in

```
re.match(r'(?:(\d+)Y)?(?:(\d+)M)?', text).groups()
```

the `groups()` method returns the portion of the matches inside the grouping parentheses. `None` is returned if the group was not matched. For example,

```
In [220]: re.match(r'(?:(\d+)Y)?(?:(\d+)M)?', '5Y3M').groups()
Out[220]: ('5', '3')

In [221]: re.match(r'(?:(\d+)Y)?(?:(\d+)M)?', '3M').groups()
Out[221]: (None, '3')
```

---

```
import re
def parse_aYbM(text):
    a, b = re.match(r'(?:(\d+)Y)?(?:(\d+)M)?', text).groups()
    if a == b == None:
        raise ValueError('input does not match aYbM')
    a, b = [int(item) if item is not None else 0 for item in (a, b)]
    return a + b/12.0

tests = [
('5Y3M', 5.25),
('5Y', 5.0),
('6M', 0.5),
('10Y11M', 10.917),
('3Y14M', 4.167),
]

for test, expected in tests:
    result = parse_aYbM(test)
    status = 'Failed'
    if abs(result - expected) < 0.001:
        status = 'Passed'
    print('{}: {} --> {}'.format(status, test, result))
```

yields

```
Passed: 5Y3M --> 5.25
Passed: 5Y --> 5.0
Passed: 6M --> 0.5
Passed: 10Y11M --> 10.9166666667
Passed: 3Y14M --> 4.16666666667
```

---

Note, it's not clear what should happen if the input to `parse_aYbM` does not match the pattern. With the code above a non-match raises `ValueError`:

```
In [227]: parse_aYbM('foo')
ValueError: input does not match aYbM
```

but a partial match may return a value:

```
In [229]: parse_aYbM('0Yfoo')
Out[229]: 0.0
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, your "non-match" is actually matching the empty string, since both pieces are optional. This returns the `groups()` as `(None, None)`. It is your code that is raising the ValueError, not the re module. Nice solution, though.

Comment: You can guard against a number of months >= 12 (as indicated in the original question) with `r"(?:(\d+)Y)?(?:(0?\d|1[01])M)?\b"` - the OP wasn't clear on whether leading zeros might be present or not. And the trailing `\b` guards against matching a leading year with invalid month.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, breaking out what the regex expression actually does!
I've found documentation on regex assumes a certain level of knowledge and is almost impossible to read if you're not there so this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `re.findall`

```
>>> def parse(m):
    s = 0
    j = re.findall(r'\d+Y|\d+M', m)
    for i in j:
        if 'Y' in i:
            s += float(i[:-1])
        if 'M' in i:
            s += float(i[:-1])/12
    print(s)


>>> parse('5Y')
5.0
>>> parse('6M')
0.5
>>> parse('10Y11M')
10.916666666666666
>>> parse('3Y14M')
4.166666666666667
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with python regex, but try something like 
`(?<year>[^Y])\D(?<month>[^M]*)\D`might just do the trick.